# Can't write user data to firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase

I'm new at this so bear with me. I'm trying to use the fire base simple login with the email and password. I have that working with this:

```
var authClient = new FirebaseAuthClient(fireRef, function(error, user) {
          if (error) {
            // an error occurred while attempting login

                if(error.code === "INVALID_EMAIL"){ 
                    $('#log_email_error').hide();
                    $('#log_pass_error').hide();
                    $('#log_email_error').html("Invalid email specified.").fadeIn();
                    $('.login_button').removeClass('login_button_success').attr('value','Log in');          
                }
                if (error.code === "INVALID_PASSWORD") {
                    $('#log_email_error').hide();
                    $('#log_pass_error').hide();
                    $('#log_pass_error').html("The specified password is incorrect..").fadeIn();
                    $('.login_button').removeClass('login_button_success').attr('value','Log in');
                }


            console.log(error);
          } else if (user) {
            // user authenticated with Firebase
            hideLogin();
            $('.userInfo_cont').show();
            $('.userInfo').html('<div> '+  user.email + ' <span class="grey">| </span> </div>');
            $('.logout').on('click',function(){
                authClient.logout();
            });

            console.log('User ID: ' + user.id + ', Provider: ' + user.provider);

          } else {
            // user is logged out
            $('.userInfo_cont').hide();
            showLogin();
          }
    });
```

But when the user registers I want to store some additional info in a firebase/users area
which I can do with this in the registration:

```
$('#submit_reg').on('click',function(){
            var firstName = $('#regFirstname').val();
            var lastName = $('#regLastname').val();
            var email = $('#regUsername').val();
            var password = $('#regPassword').val();

            authClient.createUser(email, password, function(error, user) {
              if (!error) {
                   console.log('User Id: ' + user.id + ', Email: ' + user.email);

                       authClient.login('password', {
                                          email: email,
                                          password: password,
                                          rememberMe: false
                                        });


                       hideLogin();


                        userInfo = {

                            userId : user.id,
                            firstName : firstName,
                            lastName : lastName,
                            email : user.email

                        }

                        var url = USERS_LOCATION + "/" + user.id;
                        var userRef = new Firebase(url);

                        console.log(userInfo);

                        userRef.set(userInfo);



                  }else{
                    //display error

                    alert(error);

                  }
            });



        });
```

My Problem is when I implement the read write rules like the documentation has:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users":{
     "$userid": {
        ".read": "auth.id == $userid",
        ".write": "auth.id == $userid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I get a permission denied when the user registers. So it registers the user just fine but won't write the additional data to the /users/id area.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Craig

Comment: Which line specifically? the user.id inside the userInfo object? That won't work because it won't write the userInfo object. Or do you mean in the authclient.createUser?

Comment: This is so frustrating when I used this in the permissions: ".read": "'' + auth.id == $userid",
      ".write": "'' + auth.id == $userid" and also added this code:      var newid = user.id.toString();
      var url = USERS_LOCATION + "/" + newid; It worked for a second and then stopped working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the snippet above, you're calling `login()`, and then immediately calling `set()` afterwards. This is problematic because the `login()` method is asynchronous, and you are almost always guaranteed to have called `set()` method prior to the return of the login attempt method, since `login()` is non-blocking yet makes a network call to the Firebase servers.

This means that even though you're calling `login()` with the correct email and password, you're trying to set the data before the authentication process has completed.

I would recommend moving your `set()` logic into a block that will only be executed when you are certain that the user has already authenticated, such as in the callback you passed when calling `new FirebaseAuthClient()` and detected a logged in user.